# Fastest way of reading data to webserver

Tags: node.js, database

Im looking for the fastest way of reading data to a webservice, the data is not going to update often and should be kept safe.

What is the fastest way to let a server read data(except for loading it all into memory)?

I am using Node JS

A local file? readFileSync?

Comment: You want to get data from a webservices ? In REST ?

Comment: This question is off topic. Flagged

Comment: What does "let a server read data" mean?  Read data from where?  This question needs work to meet the guidelines here on stack overflow and to be a clear question that many could answer.  I'd suggest you read this: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fs.readFileSync()` loads all data into memory so it should be used on very large files. Also it's blocking so it should only be used on the first tick of the event loop. Which means that you can use it when your service starts in places where you use `require` and other blocking calls but never in any event handler, route controller etc. You can use it if you want to read the file once and then use it. There is a non-blocking version of that function called `fs.readFile()` but it also reads the entire file into memory so while it can be used in the event handlers, it still should't be used for large files.

The fastest way to load a file and serve it is using `fs.createReadStream()` and piping it as a stream. If you're using a framework like Express, Hapi etc. then there may be convenience function that does that for you, like `res.sendFile()` in Express.

For more info see:

- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html